# How to properly use Partial View and validate its model state in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 Razor Pages.

My goal is to has a set of Partial Views (for reusability purpose) that I can use on several pages. Each Partial View has a form with its own custom post event handler (it will be processed by a code-behind of a pages that will contain this Partial View).

N.B. Some pages can contain **two or even more** different Partial Views! And I need that Partial View models to be validated **independently of each other** (in two separate custom event handlers).

Here is simplified code that I use for today. **Partial View model** (contains some data for a user):

```
public partial class User
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}    

public class UserModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public User user { get; set; }
    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    public UserModel()
    {
        user = new User();
    }
}
```

**_UserPartial.cshtml** (displays that user data):

```
@model UserModel

<div class="row text-warning">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post" asp-page-handler="UserEdited">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="user.Surname" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="user.Surname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="user.Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="user.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="user.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="user.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save user data" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Index.cshtml** (main page that contains Partial View):

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Main page";
}    

@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@Model.StatusMessage))
{
    <div class="text-center">
        <h4 class="text-warning">@Model.StatusMessage</h4>
    </div>
}    

<div class="text-center" id="mainView">
    <p>Some text in a main view</p>
    <p>Some <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">link</a> in a main view.</p>
</div>

<div class="text-center" id="userPartialView">
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_UserPartial", IndexModel.userModel);}
</div>
//Some other Partial View (which contains some data for a message)
<div class="text-center" id="userPartialView">
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_MessagePartial", IndexModel.messageModel);}
</div>
```

**Index.cshtml.cs** (code-behind of a main page):

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public static UserModel userModel { get; set; }
    //A model for some other Partial View (which contains some data for a message)
    public static MessageModel messageModel { get; set; }
    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }        

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        userModel = new UserModel();
        messageModel = new MessageModel();
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostUserEdited()
    {
        if (!userModel.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        StatusMessage = "User data was saved!";
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}
```

Problem is that **userModel.ModelState** is always **valid** even if **Name** and **Surname** are empty:
[image: Looks like UserModel is not validaiting at all]
Looks like **UserModel** is not validaiting at all.

And I have a strong feeling that I'm using Partial Views the wrong way (not the way they were supposed to be used).

So what's wrong with my code? How do I properly use Partial View and validate its model state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to have a Page Model for the partial view. Just add it as a Razor View.

[image]

Index.cshtml.cs

```
[BindProperty]
public User userModel { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public Message messageModel { get; set; }

[TempData]
public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    userModel = new User();
}

public IActionResult OnPostUserEdited()
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    if (!TryValidateModel(userModel))
    {
        return Page();
    }

    StatusMessage = "User data was saved!";
    return RedirectToPage();
}

public IActionResult OnPostMessageEdited()
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    if (!TryValidateModel(messageModel))
    {
        return Page();
    }

    StatusMessage = "Message data was saved!";
    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="text-center" id="userPartialView">
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_UserPartial", Model.userModel);}
</div>

<div class="text-center" id="messagePartialView">
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_MessagePartial", Model.messageModel);}
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: **Some pages can contain two or even more different Partial Views** - I've updated my question. So in addition to `public User userModel { get; set; }` it can be for example `public Message messageModel { get; set; }` on my main page. And I need that two models to be validated **independently of each other** (in two separate custom event handlers). I sample that you provided **ModelState.IsValid** will be **true** only if **both** Partial View models (userModel and messageModel) are valid. Is there a way to determine that for example only **userModel** fields are correct?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. They indeed validate all the model, but you can do some thing in your handler, first clear the modelstate and then validate the specify model.